# extracting key-value data from javascript json type data with bs4

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some information from HTML of a web page. 
But neither regex method nor list comprehension method works.

At http://bitly.kr/RWz5x, there is some key called encparam enclosed in getjason from a javascript tag which is 49th from all script elements of the page.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
sam = requests.get('http://bitly.kr/RWz5x')
#html = sam.text
html=sam.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


scripts = soup.find_all('script')
#your_script = [script for script in scripts if 'encparam' in str(script)][0]
#print(your_script)
#print(scripts)
pattern = re.compile("(\w+): '(.*?)'")
fields = dict(re.findall(pattern, scripts.text))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send your request to the following url which you can find in the sources tab:

[image]

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

res = requests.get("https://navercomp.wisereport.co.kr/v2/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=005930") 
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r"encparam: '(.*)'")
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
encparam = r.findall(data)[0]
print(encparam)
```

---

It is likely you can avoid bs4 altogether:

```
import requests
import re
r = requests.get("https://navercomp.wisereport.co.kr/v2/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=005930") 
p = re.compile(r"encparam: '(.*)'")
encparam = p.findall(r.text)[0]
print(encparam)
```

---

If you actually want the encparam part in the string:

```
import requests
import re
r = requests.get("https://navercomp.wisereport.co.kr/v2/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=005930") 
p = re.compile(r"(encparam: '\w+')")
encparam = p.findall(r.text)[0]
print(encparam)
```